# Merging after refactoring - detecting moved file parts

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches with the structure:

```
---(commit 1) ----- (commit 2, refactoring) ----(CONFLICT) 
        \                                      /
         \                                    /
          -----(commit 3, modifying) --------/
```

In the `commit 1` I have a file `text.txt`:

```
Part 1:
  line 1
  line 2
  line 3
Part 2:
  line 4
  line 5
  line 6
```

In `commit 2` I extract "part 2" of the `text.txt` into the `part2.txt`, so I get:

- `text.txt`:

  ```
  Part 1:
    line 1
    line 2
    line 3
  ```
- `part2.txt`:

  ```
  Part 2:
    line 4
    line 5
    line 6
  ```

In `commit 3` I slightly modify both parts of `text.txt`:

```
Part 1:
  line 1
  line 2a
  line 3
Part 2:
  line 4
  line 5b
  line 6
```

Merging two branches I expect git to be smart enough and put `line 2a` into `text.txt` and `line 5b` into `part2.txt`. Unfortunately this doesn't happen.

My expectations are based on the fact, that `git gui blame part2.txt` detects origin of the lines correctly showing `text.txt`.

My questions are:

- Why doesn't it work out of the box?
- Is there some workaround known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing the same result as you with `git gui blame part2.txt`. I'm on commit 2. `git gui blame` doesn't show `text.txt`. Anyway, to answer your questions:

- If it did 'work out of the box', what do you think would happen in the following scenario: in commit 3 you've changed `line 5` to `line 5b`. Meanwhile in commit 2, for some reason, someone has moved the 'Part 2' lines into *two identical files*: `part2a.txt` and `part2b.txt`. Should git now automatically change *both* these files to have `line 5b`?

  Git doesn't try to make these kinds of decisions--it leaves them to you.
- There is `git-rerere` if this exact conflict happens frequently. Otherwise you'll need to handle manually. Fortunately there is the `merge.conflictstyle=diff3` configuration option which displays the contents of the file in the base commit as well as the two conflicting commits. This makes it easy to see which side changed what, and what the original was. Please see the `git-merge` man page for details.

Comment: I reduced the count of lines in example files here, so git probably didn't recognized the moved part. But it works in general very good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know, there is no perfect solution. But the common case is a simple extraction. I would suggest, that git generates a conflict, but not in text.txt but in part2.txt. This would draw attention to the potential problem and also point the possible right solution. Consider https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de&fromgroups#!starred/git-users/R0R_U8I92N0 with the suggestion of new "merge.moved"=(yes|conflict|no) option.